# Confusing piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Im asked to explain why $lim_{x\to a}p(x)$ exists for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$

$$
p(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      1 & x={1\over{n}} \ \ \ \ n=1,2,3,...\\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
$$

Im confused as to what the $x={1\over{n}} \ \ \ \ n=1,2,3,...$ part of the function means. The way I interpret it is, the function equals 1 if the value of x equals a fraction $1\over n$ where n is any number in the naturals. Is this interpretation correct?
$$$$

Comment: Seems correct to me. However, the functions is not continuous everywhere except one point.

Comment: Yes I do see that, it asks why the $lim_{x\to a}p(x)$ exists for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: How well do you the epsilon-delta definition of a limit? Consider how small of a neighbourhood around $a$ could you take so that in the disc, $x$ doesn't take the form of a $\frac{1}{n}$ so that the function values close enough to $a$ but not at $a$ are the same value.

Comment: When you understand this example, [here's an even more interesting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) whose limit exists (and equals $0$) at every point.

Comment: The limit does not exist for $a=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the domain given for the function. If the domain is $$A:=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb N\right\},$$ then it is a constant function, and so is continuous. If the domain is $A\cup\{0\},$ then it is continuous at every point except $x=0.$ If the domain is $\Bbb R,$ then it is continuous at every point except the points of $A\cup\{0\}.$

---

**In response to your edit**: With a single exception, we can say that $\lim_{x\to a}p(x)=0.$ (Can you tell what the exception is?) This is because we can find some $\delta>0$ such that $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in(a-\delta,a)\cup(a,a+\delta).$

Note that this is different from saying that $f$ is continuous except at one point! In order for a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ to be continuous at a point $a,$ it is *necessary* that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exist, but it is *not* sufficient! We also require that $f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x).$ Hence, while $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists at all but one $a\in\Bbb R,$ it is discontinuous at every point of $A\cup\{0\},$ as stated in my previous version.

Comment: Yes sorry about that did not realize the mistake soon enough.

Comment: What about $lim_{x\to 1/2}p(x)$. $p(1/2) = 1$ but the neighborhood around it is 0, doesn't this cause the limit at that point to not exist. Doesn't this go the same for 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6,...

Comment: @user3258845: Since $p(1/2)=1$ but we can find a neighborhood around $1/2$ in which $p(x)=0$ for all $x$ in the neighborhood **distinct from** $1/2,$ then $\lim_{x\to1/2}p(x)=0\ne 1=p(1/2).$ This means that $p$ is discontinuous at $x=1/2,$ even though $\lim_{x\to1/2}p(x)=0.$ Similar reasoning works for any $x=1/n.$

Comment: Remember that for limits, we're only considering the behavior of the function as $x$ approaches the point $a$ (but is not equal to it).

Comment: I see now, thank you. Would the exception be at $x=0$ since $x=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over{n}}$ and the neighborhood around 0 be similar?

Comment: The exception is, indeed $x=0.$ No matter what neighborhood we take around $0,$ we can find points $x_0$ and $x_1$ in the neighborhood distinct from $0$ such that $p(x_0)=0,$ $p(x_1)=1,$ so taking $\epsilon=\frac12$ allows us to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}p(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: It would begin to oscillate between 1 and 0 too quickly near 0? Similar to $sin({1\over{x}})$ without the intermediate values

Comment: @user3258845: Well, it oscillates in a sense, yes. It doesn't do so continuously as $\sin\frac1x$ does, though. Rather, as we approach $0$ from the right, $p(x)$ keeps jumping up to $1$ at a single point before dropping right back down to $0,$ and this happens more and more frequently the closer we get. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, forget to mention only from the right. And yes this is what I mean. Thank you again.

Comment: You're very welcome!